# Workbench enters wrong data

Tags: php, mysql, workbench

I recently developed a small registration system in PHP and MySQL. In tests, it worked perfectly. However, from the first successful test, the workbench started to have problems.

Every time I enter a registration, either via PHP, or directly in the workbench, the workbench inserts the number 127 in the primary key, which, if I'm not mistaken, was the last random number I entered for testing purposes, when the test was successful.

I currently use XAMPP as a server for PHP and MySQL. I already restarted it, I already changed the server to MySQL80 and I also restarted the computer, but nothing helped.

The following is the PHP code, the "user" table and the tests in the workbench with their result, respectively:

```php
<?php
// Recepção de dados de cadastro.html
require_once("conexao.php");

$matricula = $_POST['inputMatricula'];
$nome = $_POST['inputNome'];
$email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$senha = $_POST['inputSenha'];
$login = $_POST['inputLogin'];

echo $matricula;

// Inserção de dados no BD
$result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO usuario 
    VALUES ('{$matricula}', 'Informática', 'Vespertino', '{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$senha}', '{$login}')");
```

The `usuario` table:

[image: Table "usuario"]

The contents of the `usuario` table:

[image: SELECT]
(No data in the table)

The INSERT command:

```sql
INSERT INTO usuario 
    VALUES (1234567890123456, 'Informática', 'Vespertino', 'nome', 'email', 'senha', 'login');
```

Query Results:

[image: Result]

Did you see? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

127 is the maximum value for a signed `TINYINT` column like you're using in your table. You need to use a larger data type for your primary key column.

From the MySQL documentation page on [Integer Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html):

| Type | Storage (Bytes) | Minimum Value Signed | Minimum Value Unsigned | Maximum Value Signed | Maximum Value Unsigned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TINYINT | 1 | -128 | 0 | 127 | 255 |
| SMALLINT | 2 | -32768 | 0 | 32767 | 65535 |
| MEDIUMINT | 3 | -8388608 | 0 | 8388607 | 16777215 |
| INT | 4 | -2147483648 | 0 | 2147483647 | 4294967295 |
| BIGINT | 8 | -2<sup>63</sup> | 0 | 2<sup>63</sup>-1 | 2<sup>64</sup>-1 |

If you're really planning on storing 16 digit integers in your primary key column, and you know they'll never be negative, then I'd recommend using `UNSIGNED BIGINT`.

Comment: Ohhh lol

How did I not notice that?!? Thank you so mutch!